# loading indicator autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have implemented an autocomplete functionality for a textbox in my web application.
The issue here is that my textbox is having width 100px. The loading indicator is a background css added to the textbox when user starts typing into it.

I want the loading indicator to be at the extreme right side of the page.

But since the indicated is appended to the text box(width = 100px), the loading indicator stays within it.

Please let me know how to place the loading indicator to the extreme right.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you at least give us an example of the markup you are using and the CSS you're using to position things?

Comment: The loading indicator needs to be a separate element with `position:absolute` set.

Answer (score 0):

## [Demo Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/w7cZS/)

One option is to wrap the elements in a wrapper `div` then use the `:after` pseudo selector to add in your loading indicator (simply the text `image` in the demo, replace this with `''` and use a `background-image` along with `height` and `width`). The two examples show justifying within the input to the right, or all the way across the page to the right.

HTML

```
<div class='wrapper'><input type='text' /></div>
<br>
<div class='wrapper'><input type='text' /></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
input{
    width:100px;
}
.wrapper{
    display:inline-block;
}
.wrapper:first-child{
   position:relative;
}
.wrapper:after{
   position:absolute;
   content:'Image';
    right:0;
}
```